# Stats approximation by rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, statistics

Is there a way to "switch off" statistics approximation by rasters performed by QGIS? Approximated min and max values are automatically embedded into legend labels of rasters and I would need exact ones instead. Or the only way is editing of metadata in Tiff itself?

PS: I am using QGIS 3.22 and work with Geotiffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the exact values from the layer properties by setting the extent to Whole raster and accuracy to Actual.

[image]

I tried to edit the user interface with "Interface Customization" from "QgsRasterMinMaxWidgetBase" for making the selections permanent by de-activating the other options from the menus but my trial was not successful. Maybe I made some mistake with customization.

Alternatively it is possible to make QGIS to use the exact values with  the "Stretch Histogram to Full Dataset" tool from the Raster Toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Switching accuracy to "Actual(slower)" solved the problem